# Apache2.2 Allow access though one server only

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, apache2.2

I am working on a project and it looks a lot like this:

- main site
- storage server [/directory/images/*.jpg]

I want to be able to pull images from that directory by a simple  tag. That part works, but also what I would like to do is deny everyone from direct access to the storage server. I have tried allowing only the main site IP to connect but that seems to deny access to the Main Site server also.

Visual explanation:

**customer > main site dashboard >** storage server

The **authenticated** parties listed in bold can *only* gain access to the images. Everybody else must be denied

Comment: please , paste your code

Comment: @MohammedElhag  `<Directory /var/www/>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from all

        </Directory>`

Comment: @MohammedElhag If i change it to `Deny, Allow // Deny from all // Allow from x.xx.xx.xxx` Then my main site does not display them either

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule \.jpg$ - [F]
```

That will prevent direct access to any images that has `jpg` extension but still you could be able to call it, the only problem will come from browser cache , if some one does right click on image and open it in browser , so i f you want to prevent that as well , add the following code along with above :

```
<filesMatch "\.jpg$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```